# Template argument deduction when the function returns a type composed from the template type and another

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, c++17

The title is rather hard to formulate in word, but here is what I'm trying to achieve in non-compileable code:

```
template<template <typename> class Container>
Container<int> foo() {
    return Container<int>{1,2,3};
}

int main() {
    auto bar = foo<std::vector>();
    return 0;
}
```

Basically I want a template function that can "compose" its return type from a type that is passed to it and a previously known type (in this case `int`). In this case I want a function that returns an arbitrary data type inside a container that is specified by the caller. (By arbitrary I don't mean random or undetermined at compile time, but rather that the caller has no "input" as to what the data type will be, that is determined inside the function itself).

Is this type of thing even achievable with clang or gcc with std+1z? Am I missing something really obvious? Is there a "1 line" solution spanning hundreds of character that I don't know of?

I've seen various examples of similar things around here but they all seem to assume the functions take pointers or references as arguments and fill in those containers.

Comment: And I don't know if it is your solution, but if you make the function's template parameter `template<template <typename...> class Container>` it compiles.

Comment: @ James Root  I have no idea what variadic template black magic that is, but the way more complex function that I've been struggling with for almost half an hour now just compiled and passed all unit test. So if you can please write that down as an answer... (though I would like to know the reason as to why its actually happening, but now I'm just happy it finally worked :p)

Comment: @JamesRoot That's better than my solution, though I'm a little surprised it works.

Comment: @James Root, also I'm not sure what you mean by your first question... presumably it will look like {new int(1), new int(2) ... etc}

Comment: You can pass templated alias declarations to template arguments just like a regular type. `template<typename T> using vector_container = std::vector<T>` enables you to pass `vector_container` instead.

Comment: @George Oh, somehow I completely misread something, so you can ignore my question.

Comment: The code works as is [with gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TaJhWHTLXYKluX92). According to [doc](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), this feature is intentionally disabled by default on clang, but can be enabled with `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

Comment: @cpplearner The docs indeed seem to say so. But I'm suing clang 4.0.0 and -std=c++1z and with or without the flag it compiles just the same ... so maybe the standards now specify it clearly enough for them to have removed the flag and made it default ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only trouble here is that `std::vector` is *not* a `template <typename> class`.  It is a `template <typename T, typename Alloc> class` that happens to have a default argument for the second template parameter.

One way around this is using an alias template that really does take just one parameter:

```
#include <vector>

template<template <typename> class Container>
Container<int> foo() {
    return Container<int>{1,2,3};
}

template <typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;

int main() {
    auto bar = foo<Vec>();
    return 0;
}
```

Another approach recommended in the comments is to use a variadic typename when declaring the template of the original function, which accepts any class template taking only type arguments.  And then you can instantiate it with just one argument, since the actual template has a default for the second.  This works in C++11 and above.

```
#include <vector>

template<template <typename...> class Container>
Container<int> foo() {
    return Container<int>{1,2,3};
}

int main() {
    auto bar = foo<std::vector>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is the explanation I'm looking for ^^... I didn't realize std containers actually had the second deduced template parameter and I didn't actually think to look in the header of vector....

Comment: James Root's solution seems more elegant so I'd say that maybe you should include that in the answer as well to make it complete... that is, if you think this question might ever come up on anyone's search engine, the title isn't the best and the question is somewhat niche

Answer (score 3):

A *template template parameter* with `typename...` *template template parameter list* will bind to any template name, regardless of the actual *template parameter* count. You can use this and speculatively assume the template to be instantiable with a single parameter.

```
template<template <typename...> class Container>
Container<int> foo() {
    return Container<int>{1,2,3};
}

int main() {
    auto bar = foo<std::vector>();
    return 0;
}
```

This works since `C++-11` as far as I know.

---

It would also be possible to declare a templated alias with a single parameter, making the interface more self-documenting

```
template<template <typename> class Container>
Container<int> foo() {
    return Container<int>{1,2,3};
}

template<typename T> using vector_container = std::vector<T>;
int main() {
    auto bar = foo<vector_container>();
    return 0;
}
```